# Python doesn't write in file

Tags: python, file, io

Have problem with replacing lines in file. Not sure if changes weren't written in file or data lines weren't replaced.
Here is how I tried to do this:

```
filename = "filename.txt"
f = open(filename, "r+")

lines = [line1, line2, line3]

for line in lines:
    data = f.read()
    new_line = "some new line"
    data.replace(line, new_line)

f.write(data)
f.close()
```

Where could the problem be?

Comment: What do you expect when you only open the file for reading?  Use `"w"` instead of `"r+"`

Comment: According to official documentation «'r+' opens the file for both reading and writing» (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: Is the posted code your actual code? Then what is `[line1, line2, line3]`?

Comment: This is simplified version. I have some patterns of lines I'd like to change. Here I designate them as line1, line2, line3.

Comment: It does, sorry about that.  That's what I get for commenting without researching.

Comment: have you seen the fileinput module with `inplace` file editing?  https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import fileinput 

for line in fileinput.input( filename , inplace = 1 ):
   print line.replace("SOMETHING", "SOMETHING ELSE" ), # catch for double line breaks
```

useful for editing files inline.

Comment: Except problem with adding extra '\n' between lines. I solved this using print(), with comma for all lines and print() without comma for modified lines.

Answer (score 2):

The `replace` function doesn't make changes in the object itself, but it returns a new string. So what you need is:

```
data = data.replace(line, new_line)
```

And taking Roger's comment, your code should look like this:

```
filename = "filename.txt"
f = open(filename, "r+")

lines = [line1, line2, line3]
data = f.read()

for line in lines:
    new_line = "some new line"
    data = data.replace(line, new_line)

f.write(data)
f.close()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Also move the 'data = f.read()' to outside of the loop or else you end up resetting your data every time through.

Comment: @Roger Right, I didn't realize about that.